# How to create more partitions?

Tags: partitioning, document-management

I currently have only one partition but want to create some more partitions. How can I partition my drive using Ubuntu?

And is data formatted from documents when we upgrade Ubuntu to new release?

Comment: Why do you want to create more partitions? I think we can provide better advice on how to partition your drive **if** you tell us more about why you want to change it from the way it is currently partitioned.

Comment: What sort of data and/or document changes are you asking about? In general, Ubuntu tries to never touch personal data or documents during an upgrade. (If it can avoid it.) Files which store configuration data used by Ubuntu are a different matter? They are in different categories. What exactly do want to know?

Comment: I want more partitions to save my data in different folders. Basically I have a single partition in which system is also running. And I want to know that if I upgrade my Ubuntu, Is my data  formatted? I saved my all data in the HOME Folder. Because I'm trying to upgrade my ubutu 11.04 to the new version but when I open the Upgrade manager it gives me "YOu will not get any further security fixes or critical updates. Please upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu Linux."

Comment: And when I'm pressing the upgrade button firstly started then again an error "Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server. I think may be it is due to that  I save my data in HOME FOLDER....???? "

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change your partition while you are using that partition. The best thing is to define your partitions before installing Ubuntu with the Live CD.

If while you are installing from the Live CD you select `Something else` as your choice on the `Installation Type` window, you can define the partitions as you please.

You will need to format one partition as `/`, create a swap partition (approx equal to your amount of RAM), and, if you do not want to lose documents etc.,  make a separate `/home` partition. (This also means these files are separate if you need to reinstall to the `/` partition or upgrade or try a different distro - `/home` does not need to be formatted<sup>1</sup>).

There are hundreds of how to's all over the internet on how to do this.

Following is an example setup for multibooting and sharing between Windows and Linux on 300gb.

```
sda1 = ntfs 50gb (Windows 7)
sda2 = extended 250gb (for the following)
sda3 = ext4 25gb  (/ for 10.04)
sda4 = ext4 25gb (/ for 12.04)
sda5 = ext4 100gb (/home shared between 10.04 and 12.04²
sda6 = fat32 or ntfs 100gb for a shared drive between all 3 OS's
```

All that being said - and my *preferred* method - you can still use `gparted` from a Live CD and shrink and edit partitions with a risk of losing data. Plenty of tutorials out there on how to do that also - including some on YouTube.

<sup>1</sup> Some configuration files (ones that start with a `.`, for example `.config`) can botch a different install if you use the same username.

<sup>2</sup> (each Linux OS requires a different user name to avoid conflict.)